# iPad form used to pull data from larger document

Tags: data, forms, ipad

I have an 80 page PDF document with lots of tables included and I would like to create a form on an iPad where I can pull in particular tables via a check box and then submit as a new PDF (shortened version).

Is there any software that can do this? I use Zoho forms currently to create forms on iPad but not sure how it could pull the data from the overall larger document.

Does anyone have any ideas?